bash variable problem
Apologies if this is nooby question but I am new to bash scripting and I couldn't find anything similar.
I am trying to use ffmpeg to re-encode a load of files and that requires I pull out some information first to build the transcoding command. So, I wrote this little script:
#!/usr/bin/bash -x

for file in $1
do
    ffmpeg -i "$file" 2> /tmp/ffmpeg.out
    a = "$(grep eng /tmp/ffmpeg.out | grep Audio|cut -d : -f 2|cut -d '(' -f 1)"
    echo "$a"
done

The output of the ffmpeg command creates a file with information about all the streams in the file and in this case includes the following line:
Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: eac3 (Dolby Digital Plus + Dolby Atmos), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 768 kb/s (original)
What I need from this is the number 2 between "#0:" and "(eng)" hence all the grepping and cutting. The problem I have though is that the final echo shows that the variable a doesn't contain a value, but when I run with the -x I can see a being assigned the value of '2'.
+ for file in $1
+ ffmpeg -i test.mkv
++ grep eng /tmp/ffmpeg.out
++ grep Audio
++ cut -d : -f 2
++ cut -d '(' -f 1
+ a = 2
+ echo ''

I assume I am doing something very silly here and would be grateful if somebody could put me out of my misery.

See, I knew I was doing something stupid! Thanks a lot.
